# speed motor test with IR sensor and PID algorithm

Tags: arduino-uno, pid

I'm trying to control motor speed (RPM) using an IR sensor , All I've done is to control it without PID algorithm . and it works . can someone help me with implantation with PID . I'm using Arduino Uno , L298n motor driver , IR sensor and LCD display .

here you can see the circuit :
[Circuit](https://circuitdigest.com/fullimage?i=circuitdiagram_mic/Circuit-Diagram-for-Analog-Speedometer-Using-Arduino-and-IR-Sensor.png)
and also this is the code without PID algorithm :

```
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(A5,A4,A3,A2,A1,A0);
#include <Stepper.h>
const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);
volatile byte REV; 
unsigned long int rpm,RPM;
unsigned long st=0; 
unsigned long time; 
int ledPin = 13;  
int led = 0,RPMlen , prevRPM; 
int flag = 0;
int flag1=1;
#define bladesInFan 2
float radius=1.9685;   // inch
int preSteps=0;
float stepAngle= 360.0/(float)stepsPerRevolution;
float minSpeed=0;
float maxSpeed=280.0; 
float minSteps=0;
float maxSteps=maxSpeed/stepAngle;

void setup() 
{
  myStepper.setSpeed(60);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.print("Speedometer");
  delay(2000);
  attachInterrupt(0, RPMCount, RISING); 
 }

  void loop() 
  {
    readRPM();
    radius=((radius * 2.54)/100.0);  // convering in meter
    int Speed= ((float)RPM * 60.0 * (2.0 * 3.14 * 
        radius)/1000.0);
    // RPM in 60 minute, diameter of tyre (2pi r) r is radius, 
    1000 to convert in km
    int Steps=map(Speed, minSpeed,maxSpeed,minSteps,maxSteps);

    if(flag1)
    {
       Serial.print(Speed);
       Serial.println("Kmh");
       lcd.setCursor(0,0);
       lcd.print("RPM: ");
       lcd.print(RPM);
       lcd.print("           ");
       lcd.setCursor(0,1);
       lcd.print("Speed: ");
       lcd.print(Speed);
       lcd.print(" Km/h       ");
       flag1=0;
   }
   int currSteps=Steps;
   int steps= currSteps-preSteps;
   preSteps=currSteps;
   myStepper.step(steps);
}

 int readRPM()
 { 
    if(REV >= 10 or millis()>=st+1000)                  //  IT 
   WILL UPDATE AFETR EVERY 10 READINGS or 1 second in idle
    {           
        if(flag==0)                 
           flag=1;                      
           rpm = (60/2)*(1000/(millis() - time))*REV/bladesInFan;  
           time = millis();                            
           REV = 0;
           int x= rpm;                 
           while(x!=0)
           {
              x = x/10;
              RPMlen++;
            }       
            Serial.println(rpm,DEC);
            RPM=rpm;
            delay(500);
            st=millis();
            flag1=1;
           }
        }

void RPMCount()                        
 {
   REV++;                              
   if (led == LOW)
 {
   led = HIGH;                         
 } 
  else
 {
    led = LOW;
  }
 digitalWrite(ledPin, led);
}
```

[here is the source](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-analog-speedometer-using-ir-sensor)

thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem with incorporating a PID controller? There is even a PID library for Arduino, which does the main work for you

Comment: @chrisl im a newbie and i dont know how to combine the PID code with the code above

Comment: @masut do you know what a pid controller is?

Comment: @SimSon yes three parameters proportional–integral–derivative  a control loop machine